# WhatsApp chat history transfer different Apple ID

Tags: iphone, icloud, data-transfer

I lost my WhatsApp chat history from my phone, but discovered that it was backed up on another device. Both iPhones have different Apple IDs for iCloud, so I am unable to just restore it in-app.

Is there a way to move all of the chat history without changing the Apple IDs on both phones to be the same? How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the easiest and only way to transfer WhatsApp data from one iPhone to another is if you have the same Apple ID's.